# Can the parameterized constructor be called just by calling a class method?

Tags: java, constructor

From what I know, a constructor is called when an object is created. I am confused as to how my constructor is being called even without creating an object. For e.g. consider my code:

```
public class MyAdapter {

private static final String APPID = "Foobar";
private static final String ENCPWD = "r4nd0mF0064r==";
private MyDelegate delegate = null;

public MyAdapter(MyDelegate delegate) {
    init(delegate);
}

private void init(MyDelegate delegate) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL("Some url");
        QName qname = new QName("http://blahblahblahfoo.com/", "My Service");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        delegate = service.getPort(MyDelegate.class);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public MyDelegate getDelegate() {
    return delegate;
}

public boolean authenticatePrimeMember(String userID, String userPwd) {

    MyDelegate delegate = getDelegate();

    // Other unimportant code using APPID and ENCPWD

    return false;
}
}
```

Now when I call the class method from another package, like

```
boolean auth = MyAdapter.authenticatePrimeMember(someID, LongBeard)
```

it runs perfectly! which shouldn't be happening because I did not create any object and so `delegate` couldn't be initialized. Can somebody please explain what is going on?

**UPDATE:** A possible error went past the compiler and deployed! Jeez.

Comment: I mean I get logged into my app which is not possible if the `auth` is false.

Comment: The question is why the compiler did not complain about the invocation of a non-`static` method.

Comment: Something seems amiss here - authenticatePrimeMember isn't static, so you shouldn't be able to call `MyAdapter.authenticatePrimMember(someID, somePass)` at all. That should be a compilation error. Unless MyAdapter is actually an instantiated variable? Can you post the details of the instantiated variable?

Comment: prove it. Show a minimal running example, because I'm pretty sure this won't even compile.

Comment: ideone.com could be useful for a question like this.  Copy and paste enough code to (1) show the problem; (2) compile.  Then add a link in the text of the question.

Comment: Closing on advice from OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an eclipse workspace error. The error was not detected by the compiler and the app was deployed! I do not know if that was due to the size of my legacy application which takes 10-15 mins to deploy.

Answer (score 4):

Since `authenticatePrimeMember()` is not a static method (and `delegate` isn't a static variable), you must have created a `MyAdapter` object called `MyAdapter` prior to your call, or the program wouldn't even compile. Check your code again.

Comment: No, I haven't. I am using it as an adapter to delegate the call and I have just called the method on it.

Comment: @Prince: Well, it's either that, or the code you posted differs from the one you are running.

Comment: @Prince: please show the calling code so we can avoid answers that have to guess (like this one).

Comment: @Jeroen: I wouldn't call this guessing. Based on the code given this is the only possible explanation.

Comment: This seems like an eclipse workspace error. I am re-running the app just to make sure that I have raised a valid question. I don't know how my server took off with an error still on!

Comment: @Keppil: you're right, I agree that the chances are pretty likely this is the answer. It still remains a guess though (could be a matter of not compiling the latest version), that's why I urged him to avoid these misconceptions.

Comment: @Keppil there is at least one other possible explanation:  There is another `MyAdapter` class in the other package.  The other `MyAdapter` class has a static method `public static boolean authenticatePrimeMember(String userID, String userPwd)`.  I speculate that there are other possible explanations.

Comment: @Prince: what was the problem?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel it was a compiler error but went unnoticed by the compiler and deployed to the server!

Comment: @Prince: then you should post that as a separate answer and accept that one, since this answer doesn't say that at all.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Alright, I have posted the answer but I can accept it only after 2 days!

Comment: @Keppil Your answer is correct +1 but I have posted the real reason and will mark it as the answer later to justify the question.

Comment: @Prince: Ok, if you feel that your answer is better then of course you should do that.

Comment: @emory: Sure, it's possible to construct all kinds of weird scenarios. I'll change my statement to "The only plausible explanation".

Answer (score 0):

You can call  methods by class name followed by the point operator (e.g class.method). This would explain not having instantiated an object. But this is only possible with static methods of a class since static methods can only call static methods inside the same class.

To have access to the ordinary (non-static) methods and attributes inside a class, your static method should have a reference to an object of the class.

So or you have a static method that calls a static method, or a static method that references an object so you can call non-static methods.

This means you must have either have a MyAdapter object which you are using to call the method or the authenticatePrimeMember() is static.

Unless the above helps or that you have created an object of the class, you will have to double  check your code.

EDIT: Too bad you didn't flag answer or solved, I typed all this now :(

Comment: I liked reading what you wrote. Thanks! :) I guess while you were typing I had already accepted the answer and it might not have been refreshed for you by then.